# Why are both SELECT count(PK) and SELECT count(*) so slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.3

I've got a simple table with single column PRIMARY KEY called id, type `serial`. There is exactly 100,000,000 rows in there. Table takes 48GB, PK index ca 2,1GB. Machine running on is "dedicated" only for Postgres and it is something like Core i5, 500GB HDD, 8GB RAM. Pg config was created by pgtune utility (shared buffers ca 2GB, effective cache ca 7GB). OS is Ubuntu server 14.04, Postgres 9.3.6.

Why are both `SELECT count(id)` and `SELECT count(*)` so slow in this simple case (cca 11 minutes)?

Why is PostgreSQL planner choosing full table scan instead of index scanning which should be at least 25 times faster (in the case where it would have to read the whole index from HDD). Or where am I wrong?

Btw running the query several times in a row is not changing anything. still cca 11 minutes.

Execution plan here:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=7500001.00..7500001.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=698316.978..698316.979 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=192 read=6249809
   ->  Seq Scan on transaction  (cost=0.00..7250001.00 rows=100000000 width=0) (actual time=0.009..680594.049 rows=100000001 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=192 read=6249809
 Total runtime: 698317.044 ms
```

Comment: Amount of data to read is 25x smaller and contains all keys which is sufficient to count, isn't/doesn't it ? I have run both VACUUM FULL and  ANALYZE (which btw took together more than 6hours).

Comment: Do you have a lot of concurrent DML happening on that table? The index can (and will) only be used if it's reliable. If there are many concurrent transactions (or unfinished transactions) then Postgres might not choose to use the index. Do you have a and "idle in transaction" connections that have modified that table? Also what is the value of `random_page_cost` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-RANDOM-PAGE-COST) that setting will influence the planners tendency to use an index.

Comment: You also might want to read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering the spec of a HDD is usually somewhere between 50Mb/s and 100Mb/s then for 48Gb I would expect to read everything between 500 and 1000s.

Since you have no where clause, the planner sees that you are interested in the large majority of records, so it does not use the index as this would require additional indexes. The reason postgresql cannot use the index lies in the MVCC which postgresql uses for transaction consistency. This requires that the rows are pulled to ensure accurate results. (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting)

The cache, CPU, etc will not affect this nor changing the caching settings. This is IO bound and the cache will be completely trashed after the query.

If you can live with an approximation you can use the reltuples field in the table metadata:

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl';
```

Since this is just a single row this is blazing fast.

Update: since 9.2 a new way to store the visibility information allowed index-only counts to happen. However there are quite some caveats, especially in the case where there is no predicate to limit the rows. see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans for more details.

Comment: Well if I want count ids, then scanning just index should be sufficient and would be big win because is much smaller. The average reading rate is almost 100MB/s when reads sequentialy. The thing I don't understand is why the planner does not figure out that I want to count only indexed value. I can't test the same thing right now but I'm pretty sure Oracle would figure out. Will try with Oracle tomorrow.

Comment: Looked into it. This can't be done because of the MVCC system which postgres uses. To get accurate counts, it needs to scan the table. Other databases which use different concurrency controls may allow this. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Provide source as well, please. Thx.

Comment: Just found the site few seconds ago :-). Please remove the non-related stuff from the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I did so. However part of your question was 'Why is it so slow?', there the HDD speed and cache thrashing are relevant IMHO.

Comment: @PeterTillemans: Postgres _can_ (and will) use an index for counting if it thinks that the index scan is cheaper than the table scan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name also in the case where it would not do a index scan because all records must be fetched anyway? I doubt this. If there is a where clause and fresh even statistics then I absolutely agree.

Comment: Yes even then. I just did a count on one of my smaller tables: http://explain.depesz.com/s/4Q1

Comment: I knew the reason why it's slow - I described the reason in the answer ... the point was why is it choosing slow plan.

Comment: @PeterTillemans: see also here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I was just reading that. Nice to see that has been added since 9.2. However in the last point of the summary it mentioned that it is dependent if an index scan would be used for a normal select. Time for another edit.